# nesting if statements

Tags: coding-style, if-statement, nested

Which is better, nesting an if statement inside the if block, or inside the else block?

a.

```
if (cond1)
   if (cond2){
      statement1;
      statement2;
      ...
   }
   else {
      statement3;
      statement4;
      ...
   }

else {
   statement5;
   statement6;
   ...
}
```

b.

```
if (!cond1) {
   statement5;
   statement6;
   ...
}

else if (cond2) {
   statement1;
   statement2;
   ...
}

else {
   statement3;
   statement4;
   ...
}
```

Thanks for the replies so far. I just edited the options, but my main concern really is just this: If you have a choice, (by changing the conditional expressions) is it better to nest an if statement in a higher level if's if block or its else block? (a) is just an example of nesting the if in the if block, and (b) is an example of nesting the if in the else block. Thanks again for everyone's time.

Comment: You should edit your example per Justin's comment.  Are you looking for `if (cond) ... else if (cond2) {...} else {...}` versus `if (cond) ... else { if (cond2) {...} else {...}}`? Or as Justin says, the nested if versus the logical and? Thanks.

Comment: This is super ambiguous to read (and I don't even know the correct parse) so please do add curly braces around the blocks in the first case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Thanks for clarifying the question.  The question is now really one of style and comes down to what is most readable.  Generally speaking the latter is nicer when you have a true multi-way conditional, meaning at some point in the code there are three possible conditions all equally likely and equally sensible.  The former is cleaner perhaps when semantically cond1 is the *real* driver, and cond2 is a kind of subordinate condition that people only think about when cond1 is true.

**OLD ANSWER:**

Here is one interpretation of the question ("nesting inside of then"):

```
if (cond1) {
    if (cond2) {
        A
    }
} else {
    B
}
```

This should be written, as Justin points out, as

```
if (cond1 && cond2) {
    A
} else {
    B
}
```

*unless there is code that needs to be in the `if cond1` part that is **not** in the scope of the `if cond2`.*

Another interpretation of your question ("nesting inside of else") is:

```
if (cond1) {
    A
} else {
    if (cond2) {
        B
    }
}
```

In this case you should rewrite as

```
if (cond1) {
    A
} else if (cond2) {
    B
}
```

Because it better expresses the idea of the multiway conditional.  Again if there is something that belongs in the scope of not cond1 but not in the scope of the cond2, then you need to nest.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How can one of them be better when they aren't equivalent? A nested if is, at its simplest, an "Is this true? If it is, is that also true?". An else if is an "Is this true? If not, is that true?".

Comment: I'm just guessing the OP's intent.  If there is no edit forthcoming I will withdraw the answer.

Comment: @ ray: Yes, that is my intent. I just wanted to know whether it is better to nest an if statement in an if block or in an else block.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Bill.  I edited my answer to address the updated question (at the top).

Comment: @Ray when you said that the question is now really one of style and comes down to what is most readable, are you saying that both are equivalent performance-wise (the compiler considers them equivalent)?

Comment: Yes, @Bill, virtually all compilers today will consider your two options equivalent or very nearly so, differing I think at most by one conditional branch instruction or one jump instruction.  Many modern compilers are capable of reordering larger chunks of code than a three-way if-statement so yes, I would consider the stylistic choice here the primary driver.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your examples don't match. I would rewrite the first to be:

```
if(cond && cond2)
{

}
else
{

}
```

The only time I would nest if statements like your first example would be:

```
if(cond)
{
    if(cond2)
    {
        // Stuff that requires both conditions to be true.
    }

    // Stuff that requires only the first condition to be true.
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Your two versions aren't equivalent! Consider `cond = true` and `cond2 = false`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - My two versions aren't meant to be equivalent. The second is meant to show a different condition when I would use nested if statements.

Comment: That's fine IF the whole of your `if` block is another `if` statement. If you have other bits of code before or after that second `if` statement then attempting to combine it into one single decision structure would likely result in some nasty duplication of code.

Comment: @Justin: Your first version also isn't equivalent to the OP's first version. I don't actually know which way round the OP's first version is interpreted, but neither way is the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: In that case, I don't think either is necessarily better.  In my opinion, (b) is much easier to read and follow logically.  Either one will do though!

Does the else in (a) go with the first if statement or the second? By the way you indented, I would assume that it goes with the first if statement, but if that is the case, then your two examples aren't the same logically.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
<?php 
    if(find_user($email)){
        if(check($email,$password)){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            setcookie("name",$_SESSION['name'],time() +40);
            header("Location: index.php");
        }else{
            echo "incorrect email or password";
        }
    }else{
        echo "username not found !";
    }
    ?>
    
    <?php 
    if(find_user($email)){
        if(find_user($name)){
            if(check($password,$passwordcp)){
           $f = "readme.txt";
           $file = fopen($f,"a+");
           fwrite($file,"\n".$email.","$password.",".$name);
           fclose($file);
            }else{
            echo "Password contains invalid characters";
        }else{
            echo "username already exist !";
        }
    }else{
        echo "email already exist !";
    }
    ?>
```